# Isomorphisms of extensions for differentials

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring, $\mathfrak a \trianglelefteq A$ an ideal and assume $\mathfrak a^2 = 0$. Given an automorphism $f : A \to A$ of $A$ such that $f(a) \equiv a \pmod{\mathfrak a}$ and $f(a) = a$ for all $a \in \mathfrak a$, is $f$ necessarily the identity map?

So we write $f(a) = a + n$ for some $n \in \mathfrak a$ and try to show that $n=0$, but besides the obvious $n^2 = 0$, I can't seem to get anything.

Matsumura, in his Commutative Algebra book (Chapter 10, Differentials, page 177-178) claims that the identity map is the unique map with these properties listed above but did not give a proof.

Edit : I am adding here the quote from Matsumura's book which got me wondering.

"By an **extension of $C'$ by $N$** we mean a triple $(C,\varepsilon,i)$ of a ring $C$, a surjective homomorphism of rings $\varepsilon : C \to C'$ and a map $i : N \to C$, such that: (1) $\ker \varepsilon$ is an ideal whose square is zero (hence a structure of $C'$-module on $\ker \varepsilon$), and (2) the map $i$ is an isomorphism from $N$ onto $\ker \varepsilon$ as $C'$-modules. Therefore, identifying $N$ with $i(N)$ we get $C' \simeq C/N$, $N^2 = (0)$. An extension is often represented by the exact sequence $0 \to N \overset i{\longrightarrow} C \overset{\varepsilon}{\longrightarrow} C' \to 0$. Two extensions $(C,\varepsilon,i)$ and $(C_1,\varepsilon_1,i_1)$ are said to be **isomorphic** if there exists a ring homomorphism $f : C \to C_1$ such that $\varepsilon_1 \circ f = \varepsilon$ and $f \circ i = i_1$. Such $f$ is necessarily unique."

It follows trivially that an isomorphism of extensions is an isomorphism of rings, but I don't believe (mostly after Hanno's answer, I must say) that it has to be an isomorphism.

Comment: Perhaps the last line of the quoted text was supposed to be "Such $f$ is necessarily an isomorphism." which is true, and would make sense cosidering that he wants to call them isomorphic.

Comment: @Nex : Yeah but it's a big step between being an isomorphism and being a unique isomorphism and Matsumura's statements are usually precise, the fact that $f$ is an isomorphism is super trivial at this stage. So I'm confused as to what he actually wanted to say. Anyway, might have been a bad case of copy-paste or just a mistake. I got my answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. To begin, such automorphisms are in bijection with $A/{\mathfrak a}$-module derivations $D: A/{\mathfrak a}\to{\mathfrak a}$ by $D\mapsto (a\mapsto a + D(a))$. Suppose now that $A=R[x]/(x^2)$ and that ${\mathfrak a} := (x)$. Then $A/{\mathfrak a}\cong R$ as rings, and under this isomorphism ${\mathfrak a}$ corresponds to the regular $R$-module. Hence $A/{\mathfrak a}$-module derivations $A/{\mathfrak a}\to {\mathfrak a}$ are just derivations $R\to R$.

Comment: So either Matsumura is wrong or I understand his statement incorrectly (I totally agree with your explanations, there is no doubt there). Do you have the book? Can you check if I translated the statement correctly? I only made the change that if $A,A'$ are two extensions of $B$ by $N$, I assumed $A=A'$ (which is a particular case, hence cannot make the statement less true). Since the identity map trivially gives an isomorphism of extensions in this case, I was wondering if there were others (and you found many).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Could you give the full formulation of the statement you are interested in?

Comment: I edited the question to add the quote. There is nothing missing after the statement that $f$ should be unique ; he starts talking about another topic (trivial extensions) afterwards.

Comment: Do you have an specific counterexample on mind?