# An extension of a ring by a module has a section if and only if it is the trivial extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

On his book *Commutative Algebra*, Matsumura defines the notion of an extension of a ring $C'$ by a $C'$-module $N$ (the definition is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1514675/394668)). In (25.B), he defines the trivial extension $C'*N$ and then he claims that an extension $(C,\varepsilon,i)$ of $C'$ by $N$ is trivial if and only if $\varepsilon$ has a section that is a ring homomorphism.

On the one hand, it is easy to verify that the section $C'\to C'*N,c'\mapsto(c',0)$ is a ring homomorphism. But I am having trouble proving the other implication. Here are my thoughts so far: If $s:C\to C'$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\varepsilon\circ s=\text{id}_C$, then the map
\begin{align*}\varphi:C&\to C'*N\\
c&\mapsto(\varepsilon(c),c-s(\varepsilon(c')))
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism of abelian groups that sends $1_{C'}$ to $1_{C'*N}$. Hence, it suffices to check multiplicativity of $\varphi$.

But this is what I am having trouble with. How does one proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\varphi(cd)=(\varepsilon(cd),cd-s\varepsilon(c)s\varepsilon(d))$ and \begin{align*}
\varphi(c)\varphi(d)
&=(\varepsilon(c),c-s\varepsilon(c))(\varepsilon(d),d-s\varepsilon(d))\\
&=(\varepsilon(cd),c(d-s\varepsilon(d))+d(c-s\varepsilon(c)))\\
&=(\varepsilon(cd),2cd-s\varepsilon(d)c-s\varepsilon(c)d).
\end{align*}
(In the second equality, we have used the $C/i(N)\cong C'$-module structure of $i(N)$.) So $\varphi(cd)=\varphi(c)\varphi(d)$ if and only if $0=cd+s\varepsilon(c)s\varepsilon(d)-s\varepsilon(d)c-s\varepsilon(c)d$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
cd+s\varepsilon(c)s\varepsilon(d)-s\varepsilon(d)c-s\varepsilon(c)d
&=(c-s\varepsilon(c))d-(c-s\varepsilon(d))s\varepsilon(d)\\
&=-(c-s\varepsilon(c))(d-s\varepsilon(d)),
\end{align*}
which is a product of two elements of $i(N)$, hence zero, since $i(N)^2=(0)$.